# Large file upload using CSOM for provider hosted app (user + app policy)

Tags: 2013, file-upload, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem, large-file

I m trying to upload large file using CSOM code. Code is throwing the following error -

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: bytesToCopy

```
clientContext.RequestTimeout = 10000000;
var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
fileCreationInformation.ContentStream = memoryStream;
fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = false;
fileCreationInformation.Url = fullFilePath;
file = fldr.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Update**

I am referring to the following MSDN help. I am using the ContentStream property for FileCreationInformation.
[Upload large files sample app for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904536.aspx)

Comment: Where are you using this? On premise or office 365?

Comment: Use the REST api or custom web part of file upload for upload the large file

Comment: Forgot to mention it, I have on-premise SharePoint app

Comment: Have you checked this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/deac7cb7-c677-47b0-acdc-c56b32dfaac8/uploading-bigger-files-using-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

My code was

```
var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
fileCreationInformation.ContentStream = memorystream;
```

The above code was throwing error to me. I resolved it by converting MemoryStream object to Stream object. So the new code is,

```
var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
byte[] documentBytes = memorystream.ToArray();
Stream s = new MemoryStream(documentBytes);
fileCreationInformation.ContentStream = s;
```

This fixed my issue. Hope this helps.